# How can i make a video play and pause in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dom, video

Hello i am working on a wordpress website using visual composer.
In a page section i have a background video which i would like to
pause and play with a button. Now i have the button on the bottom right of the screen and i am able to pause the video, but i have trouble with finding the code to play it again. Basically i would like the button to toggle the video from a play/pause state. This is my current code and i am lost on how to proceed.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

   jQuery(".sound-toggle").click( function (){

   /* pause the video in the page section */ 
   jQuery('.mk-section-video video').get(0).pause();

   /* change button icon when toggled */ 
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('mk-moon-volume-2 mk-moon-volume-mute-2');
   });

}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

   jQuery(".sound-toggle").click( function (){

   if(jQuery(".mk-section-video video").paused){


   /* pause the video in the page section */ 
   jQuery('.mk-section-video video').get(0).pause();

   /* change button icon when toggled */ 
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('mk-moon-volume-2 mk-moon-volume-mute-2');

   }else{

     /* play the video in the page section */ 
   jQuery('.mk-section-video video').get(0).play();

   /* change button icon when toggled */ 
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('mk-moon-volume-2 mk-moon-volume-mute-2');

   }

   });

}};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! But unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, First put play() and second one is pause()... Sorry again

Comment: No problem, i changed it around and i can pause but i cannot play the video again. Suggestions?

Comment: .paused should be .get(0).paused
it is fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp), `play`a video in JavaScript is the same than `pause`, so :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //........

    bindPlayVideo();
}):

function bindPlayVideo() {
    $('#yourButtonId').click(function() {
        var videoEl = $('.mk-section-video video').get(0);
        videoEl.play();
    });
```